# How to turn on WIFI via cmd?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

My laptop's WiFi button is not working.
Is there any command in Windows to turn on WiFi ?

Comment: Sometimes the button is built in by the manufacturer and disconnects power to the WIFI via hardware and works without OS interaction, Other times it is just a windows notification button that relies on OEM software. If you can identify the laptop model it may be possible to tell if there is a software solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To do this using netsh:

Get the Interface Name:

`netsh interface show interface`

Enable the interface:

`netsh interface set interface "Interface Name" enabled`

To complete the solution to your problem, you could create a shortcut, and make it run on the startup of Windows. For example, if the name of your wireless adapter in netsh is Wi-Fi, the shortcut would look like this (one line):

`C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:administrator "C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe interface set interface \"Wi-Fi\" enabled"`

The runas command ensures that the command is ran as administrator, which is required to bring the interface up or down. The /savecred switch will save the credentials, which might be asked the first time, but usually not after that.

Comment: I'm getting "This network connection does not exist"

Comment: Hi @CodyBugstein make sure that you write the Interface Name using the correct case. This is one of the gotchas...hope it helps

Comment: The `runas` command doesn't help because you don't get read admin permissions.

Answer (score 7):

Get NIC list and index number:

```
wmic nic get name, index
```

Enable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
```

Disable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

Comment: The above strongly suggests to have come from this link verbatim - please next time cite your sources: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/enabledisable-network-interface-via-command-line/17a21634-c5dd-4038-bc0a-d739209f5081

Comment: In one line of code. For a batch file use %% - `WMIC PATH Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE "Name LIKE '%%Wireless%%'" CALL enable` . For typing in the console - `WMIC PATH Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE "Name LIKE '%Wireless%'" CALL enable`

Answer (score 1):

You could use DevCon to disable the device from the commandline. Think of DevCon.exe as a commandline device manager, but that would just turn the adaptor on and off.

You're prolly better off using netsh commands.

Comment: Here's more about devcon: https://rickosborne.org/blog/2007/02/stupid-windows-tricks-restart-network-adapter-when-it-hangs/