# How to toggle Wi-Fi in Windows 10 via the command line?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, command-line, netsh

[image: Image: Wi-Fi Toggle button in Windows 10]

If I try to connect to a wireless network using `netsh wlan connect` when the Wi-Fi toggle switch is off, the following error is displayed:

> Function WlanGetAvailableNetworkList returns error 2150899714:
>
> The wireless local area network interface is powered down and doesn't support the requested operation.

I've tried re-enabling the wireless interface using `netsh int set int`, but that didn't seem to re-toggle the Wi-Fi button. How do I connect to a wireless network via the command line if the Wi-Fi toggled switch is disabled? I suspect the similar problem occurred with a laptop–that had a corrupted Windows 10 upgrade, which led to explorer.exe not working–when I tried to connect it to the Wi-Fi.

The network interface has already been enabled, so that isn't the problem. It seems separate from the Wi-Fi toggle switch.

***For future readers:*** The currently marked answer is very good, but requires the Settings app to be functioning. This may not always in crippled installs (happened in a corrupt Windows 10 update), where only the command prompt is functioning. Please add a new answer if a command-prompt-only method is made available.

Note: This question is not a duplicate of [Can't enable "Wi-Fi" interface via command line (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1331506/cant-enable-wi-fi-interface-via-command-line-windows-10). That question relates to a specific error message (which appears to be a bug unrelated to this issue). This question was created as a follow up to the more specific problem of toggling the Wi-Fi button in Windows 10 via cmd.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 It needs to be done in two steps. First you need to enable network adapter and then you can connect to wifi. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/696270/how-to-turn-on-wifi-via-cmd) you can find commands to enable/disable network adapter (see answer posted by `abzcoding`. After enabling wlan adapter try connecting `netsh wlan connect`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a batch script that will toggle the state of *Wi-Fi* either **ON** or **OFF** to the opposite state it in when it runs. This uses `ms-settings:network-wifi` to open the **Wi-Fi Settings** screen, and then it presses the space key one time using [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) to toggle. This method builds a dynamic vb script with a batch script and then executes the vb script with [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) to emulate pressing the space key.

### GUI Toggle

[image]

---

### Script

**Note:** *Just save this to a text file with a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension and execute it to run.*

```
@ECHO OFF

explorer ms-settings:network-wifi
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " "                                >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
EXIT
```

---

---

### Further Resources

- [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app)
- [SendKeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [CScript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 You can add `NETSH WLAN CONNECT SSID=<SSID> NAME=<WLAN Profile Name>` to the bottom of the script (just above the `EXIT`)—and I'll edit to add as an example if needed once I hear back from you if this method will suffice to turn ON the wi-fi and then connect to it via `NETSH` afterwards